# Transformation of non-categorical discrete feature

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-scaling

> Goal: Predict a performance score of a place of interest in a given city based on (amongst others), the number of restaurants within 200m. $\\$
>
> Dataset: $D$ with a feature $x$ indicating the $\textit{number of restaurants within 200m}$ of some place of interest (target varible, $y$)
>
> $\textbf{Question}$: How can x be tranformed, such that it fits e.g a gaussian distribution for better modelling?

I am not sure how this is handled. If it was a categorical variable, it could just be a one-out-of-k encoding.

Are there any standard approaches to this? A logarithmic transformation does not yield anything useful.